# Database connection failed when reading from copy

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using kafka source connector for capturing CDC from RDS Aurora Postgres. Getting this error.
Please assist if someone know this issue.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1074)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:37)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:158)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:123)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending(V3PGReplicationStream.java:80)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.readPending(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:397)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:119)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:99)
    ... 5 more 
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1155)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:639)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.setNetworkTimeout(PGStream.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.hasMessagePending(PGStream.java:139)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1109)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1072)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Seems like you have a network connection issue

Comment: I have a similar issue and it happens consistently. Not network related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debezium 1.1.0.CR1 already handles auto-reconnects in these cases https://debezium.io/blog/2020/03/13/debezium-1-1-c1-released/

Answer (score 0):

yes Jiri Pechanec.  Actually the problem was with debezium version. older version does not support Postgres auto-connect facility if connection lost for some temporary issue. Now new version of debezium (1.1.0) support auto-connect facility.